# Solving a possible case of "static initialization order fiasco"

Tags: c++, static, sfml

I've spent quite a while on this problem and was wondering if any of you could help me out although this may be a silly question.

I am making a game in SFML also using a module called TGUI. I created my own class to interpret events for TGUI with the following class:

```
#include "TGUIEvents.h"
#include <vector>
#pragma once
class TGUIEventHandler
{
public:
    static std::vector<TGUIEvent*> events;
    ~TGUIEventHandler();
};
```

The TGUIEvent structure looks like this and is connected to different buttons or widgets that are used by TGUI:

```
#include "MenuStructure.h"
#include <TGUI/TGUI.hpp>
#pragma once
enum TGUIEvents : int{
    MESSAGE_BOX_OK=1,
    MESSAGE_BOX_YES=2,
    MESSAGE_BOX_NO=3,
    LOG_IN=4,
};

struct TGUIEvent
{
    MenuStructure menu; //Menu to remove
    TGUIEvents eventType; //Type of event
    std::vector<std::string> arguments;
};
```

Before, I was writing my code in debug mode but decided to switch to release mode. When I switched to release mode however I started to notice an issue. If I did not click any buttons and therefore did not add anything to the static member of 'events' in TGUIEventHandler, 7 times out of 10 the program would crash when closing. It comes up with something along the lines of:

```
Exception thrown at 0x77DF918D (ntdll.dll) in Poker.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

This can happen even if I do not launch the game itself, but just launch an empty program with nothing in 'main'. After reading up on things for a little bit, I realize this could be an issue known as "static initialization order fiasco", although I am not sure. Why is this happening only in release mode and not debug mode? Why does this happen only when it has not been used before? Why does this happen in general and how can I fix it?
I am going to try a few methods which may result in getting rid of the static datatype altogether, but any other way that keeps this static data type I would greatly appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: You can control static initialization in a sense by using static functions that return references to local static objects instead of using statis members or globals.

Comment: Static initialization between translation units is unspecified and may change for any reason, including changing to a release configuration.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)